# I need android SDK for update UUID of Beacon

Tags: android, sdk, altbeacon, estimote, beacon

I have bought [ibks 105 beacon](http://accent-systems.com/product/ibks-105/) but the UUID comes to 0. The company, tell me that this beacon works with standart protocol. And the company doesnt have SDK.

I am looking for SDK for update UUID, major and minor values.

I have try with Estimote and kontakt sdk but they need apikey for be initilized. And AltBeacon doesnt provide any beacon configuration SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **there is no standard protocol, API or SDK to configure beacon identifiers**. There are only standard formats for transmitting and detecting beacons.  This is what is defined by the AltBeacon standard and what is decoded by the Android Beacon Library.

To configure beacon identifiers **you must use an app or SDK provided by your beacon vendor**.  There must have been a miscommunication when you were told otherwise.  You should ask again.

Full disclosure: I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library project.

Answer (score 0):

The company from which you bought the beacon DOES offer an APP (for both iOS and Android) which will allow you to configure the UUID and all the other parameters available in the beacon:

**iOS:** https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/ibks-config-tool/id929525388?mt=8

**Android:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accent_systems.ibks_config_tool&hl=es

Also, in the support website, you can find enough information to help you implement your own application to configure the UUID (or everything you need). The connection with the beacon is made using the default `BluetoothAdapter` and `BluetoothGatt` in Android, and for iOS, using the default `CoreBluetooth` framework. Once you connect and you know and understand the GATT structure, it is easy to modify the parameters and transmitted values.

Even more, there is an SDK for Android and some code exmple APP for iOS.

Check everything here:

https://accent-systems.com/support/

Or write a support ticket. **WE** will answer in less than 24 hours.

BR,